# What does "call" and "mind" means in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

in [economist](https://www.economist.com/united-states/2019/12/16/how-impeachment-works-outside-america) article, There is a sentence :

**"Although “impeachment” most often calls to mind embattled occupants of 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, it is far from a mere American phenomenon."**

I want to know the meaning of this sentence and specifically what does "call" and "mind" means in this sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Call to mind* is an idiom meaning "remember", or "remind".

Definition [here](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/call-to-mind?s=t)